# Magento 2 Custom Module Not Accessible In Other Users

Tags: php, xml, acl, magento2

I have simple grid listing custom module in magento 2 admin, but I can not access it in other users then default admin,

Here are my files

**acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Spaarg_Tables::tables" title="tables" sortOrder="100"/>
 <!--AddMenuAcl-->
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Spaarg. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Spaarg_Tables::spaarg_tablesgrid_index" title="Tables" module="Spaarg_Tables"  sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Spaarg_Tables" action="tables/tablesgrid/index" resource="Spaarg_Tables::spaarg_tablesgrid_index"/>
<!--AddMenu-->
    </menu>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <!-- payment-group -->
        </section>
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <!-- carrier-group -->
        </section>
        <section id="tables" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="330" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <!-- tables-group -->
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Here is my controller 
**Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Spaarg\Tables\Controller\Adminhtml\TablesGrid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    protected $resultPage;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();  
        $this->resultPage->setActiveMenu('Spaarg_TablesGrid::tables');
        $this->resultPage ->getConfig()->getTitle()->set((__('TablesGrid')));
        return $this->resultPage;
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
      return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Spaarg_TablesGrid::tables');
    }

}
```

It is showing checked in user roles for my modules,
I am new to magento, it would be great if someone can suggest a way to handle this.

Comment: @ManthanDave thanks for your quick response, yes, They are admin users.

Comment: No, I don't need any, i need only two modules to be accessed in that user, catalog and my custom module, other then that i have clear magento cache and performed reindexing too, but till now no luck.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you said, it shows my module when I select 'ALL' as resource access, but it is not working when I use 'CUSTOM' selection by checkboxes.

Comment: Yes its because if your module is depends on some another default module then its not working so you need to take care that you can give access to depended modules as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130115/discussion-between-anand-and-manthan-dave).

Comment: @Anand I am also facing the same issue. can you please share how you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">                            
                            <resource id="Spaarg_Tables::tables" title="tables" sortOrder="100"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: you have to post magento related question inside, http://magento.stackexchange.com/